# What is $(\frac{d}{dx})^\frac{d}{dx}$?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

### How I got interested:-

Yesterday I watched [this](https://youtu.be/O85OWBJ2ayo) new video from 3blue1brown.

And I realized that we can use the formula -

$\textstyle\displaystyle{e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}}$

to almost anything.

We can define [matrix powers](https://youtu.be/O85OWBJ2ayo), [matrix to the power of a matrix](https://youtu.be/csfb_0Bl0ss), [exponential derivative](https://youtu.be/VI6ZlnkuxuA) etc.

So I started wondering about what $(\frac{d}{dx})^\frac{d}{dx}$ would mean.

### My approach:-

Obviously in order to use the previously mentioned formula, we have to write $(\frac{d}{dx})^\frac{d}{dx}$ as a power of $e$. And we can do that very easily.

$\textstyle\displaystyle{\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^\frac{d}{dx}=e^{\frac{d}{dx}\ln(\frac{d}{dx})}}$

Now if we use the formula then we get

$\textstyle\displaystyle{\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^\frac{d}{dx}}$

$\textstyle\displaystyle{=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\ln\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)\right)^n}$

Well obviously $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}$ makes sense. But what about $\ln^n(\frac{d}{dx})$?

To make sense of it, I used the tailor series of $\ln(x)$.

$\textstyle\displaystyle{\ln(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}(x-1)^k}{k}}$

$\textstyle\displaystyle{\implies\ln^n\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}(\frac{d}{dx}-1)^k}{k}\right)^n}$

So,

$\textstyle\displaystyle{\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^\frac{d}{dx}}$
$\textstyle\displaystyle{=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}\left(\frac{d}{dx}-1\right)^k}{k}\right)^n}$

### My confusion:-

When I used the series expansion for $e^x$, it was very easy to understand because the radius of convergence in $\infty$.

But while using the series expansion for $ln(x)$ it doesn't make much of a sense to me, because the taylor series converges if $0\lt x\leq 2$.

But what does $0\lt\frac{d}{dx}\leq 2$ mean?

I mean differential operator is not a number which we can compare with other numbers.

So I am stuck here.

## Questions:-

**(1)** Is my approach correct?

**(2)** How to make sense of $\ln(\frac{d}{dx})$? Or can we just ignore the convergence condition of the taylor series of $\ln(x)$?

**(3)** Are there other easier approaches for defining $(\frac{d}{dx})^\frac{d}{dx}$? And what they are?

Comment: 1 is just the identity, same as in the Taylor series for $e^{d/dx}$. The issue there is dividing by $d/dx+1$, which is an ambiguous operation without a boundary condition.

Comment: You can use the series $$\log x=\log a+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(x-a)^n}{na^n},$$ which holds for $0<x\le 2a$.

Comment: @vitamin d. This one might be helpful.

Comment: You might be interested in my essay on matrix-power-to-matrix and matrix-tetrated at http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/PascalMatrixTetrated.pdf . The index of my tetration-stuff is at http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/ and has a little abstract of the text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a interpretation of the symbol $(d/dx)^{d/dx}$ that is independent of summation.  The steps I'll take are entirely formal.  From the Euler representation of the gamma function,
$$ a^s = \frac{1}{\Gamma{(-s)}} \int_0^\infty e^{-a u}u^{-s}\frac{du}{u} $$
let $a \to d/dx$ and $s \to d/dx.$  Let this operator act on a function $f(x).$  (We say nothing about the properties of $f,$ or even if such an $f$ can exist.) Then

$$(d/dx)^{d/dx} f(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma{(-d/dx)} } \int_0^\infty f(x- (u + \log{u}) \  ) \frac{du}{u} $$ where we have used the Taylor series in operator form,

$$ (1) \quad  \exp{(a \  d/dx)} f(x) = f(x + a).$$

The reciprocal gamma function containing the $d/dx$ is closely related to the inverse Laplace transform.  Let's use the Hankle contour representation of the reciprocal gamma,

$$ (2) \quad \frac{1}{\Gamma(z)} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_c e^s s^{-z} ds .$$  Then we can say

$$(d/dx)^{d/dx} f(x) = \int_c \frac{ds}{2 \pi i} \  e^s s^{d/dx} \int_0^\infty f(x- (u + \log{u}) \  ) \frac{du}{u} $$
$$=  \int_c \frac{ds}{2 \pi i} \  e^s \int_0^\infty f(x- (u + \log{u}) + \log s \  ) \frac{du}{u}$$ where (1) has been used again.

For fun, try $f(x) = e^{a \ x} - e^{ b \ x}.$  Then the above prescription gives us

$$(d/dx)^{d/dx} f(x) =  \int_c \frac{ds}{2 \pi i} \  e^s \Big( a^a \ e^{a \ x} \Gamma(-a) s^a -
b^b \ e^{b \ x} \Gamma(-b) s^b ) \Big) =$$
$$ =  a^a \ e^{a \ x} -  b^b \ e^{b \ x} $$ where the innermost integral was done by Mathematica (first line of previous expression), and outer one by using (2) (final expression).

All this is forma manipulation. For more rigor, you'd have to define a class of functions for validity, define the Hankle contour, etc.  Even the first step is problematic: should the reciprocal gamma come before the integral, or after it?

Comment: I am having an existential anxiety after reading the comments and answers.

Comment: Thanks for the chuckle.

Comment: To be honest I am kinda confused. You just answered my question and at the end you said that your answer is problematic. I don't get it. Is there no definite definition of $(\frac{d}{dx})^\frac{d}{dx}$?

Comment: You could take my answer as a definition.  You could take your double sum as a definition.  The consequences of these definitions are the important thing.  They could agree, but probably not.  An interesting topic you might want to study --  and if you know integral calculus it's within your reach --  is fractional derivatives.  There are at least two definitions that I am aware of, and they have different consequences.  It's easy to right down a symbol (d/dx)^c where c is not an integer.  To make sense of it, it's turned into an integral. And that's where it gets interesting...

Answer (score 3):

Before answering your question, I want to point out an important note, which is rarely mentioned by the YouTubers revealing the secrets of $i^i$.

When $x$ isn't a real number, a function $\exp(x)$, which is often denoted as $e^x$ is not a number $e$ times itself $x$ times which is a literal definition of power. It makes sense to write it as $e^x$, because it often has one or both of the properties: $\exp(x+y) = \exp(x)\exp(y)$ and $\frac{d}{dx}\exp x = \exp x$. You can **define** $x^y=\exp(y\log x)$. But this definition is problematic in a broad sense (discontinuity, multi-branching and so on).

So in reality, when $x$ is not a real number, you naturally meet either $x^p$, where $p$ is either integer or real, or $\exp(x)$. Writing $x^y$ is unjustified abuse of notation.

Having said that, if $p,q$ are element of some algebra, you can define:
$$
\exp(p) =1+p+\frac{p^2}{2!}+\frac{p^3}{3!}+\ldots,\\
\log(1+p) =1-p+\frac{p^2}2-\frac{p^3}3+\ldots,\\
p^q = \exp(q\log(p)).
$$
Or use any other definition of log you are offered in the comments.
At it would be possible to express $p^p$ as a polynomial in $p$. Will it converge for $p=d/dx$ when applied to some function $f(x)$? Who knows? even $e^{d/dx}$ doesn't have this property (consider $f(x)=e^{e^{x^2}}$).

In general, when one gets a question “how can you define $\nabla^\nabla$” ($0/0$, $0^0$, $1+2+3+4\dots$, you name it), it's always good to ask “in what kind of problem one would need this concept or notation?”. Because the answer usually will depend on it. And without this question, any definition is as good.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say, but your answer doesn't really answers my question properly. You have just gone over the basical concepts without giving mathematical details. Without the mathematical details I can't accept your answer.

Comment: That's fair. It's not an answer. It's a comment which is too long to be a comment.

Comment: To address your questions: 1) there is no problem with it per see, you are allowed to define things as you want; 2) one might define $D=\ln(d/dx)$ as an operator for which $e^D = d/dx$; until you have introduced the metrics in the space of operators, you can't speak about convergence; operator space is also non-orderable, so writing  $0<d/dx<2$ makes no sense; 3) Probably no. But I have a hard time justifying $(d/dx)^{d/dx}$ in the first place to compare approaches

Answer (score 3):

To answer question 3: You could try using [the power series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5Ex+series+at+x%3D1) of $x^x$ at $x=1$
\begin{align}
x^x &= 1 + (x-1) + (x-1)^2 + \frac{1}{2}(x-1)^3 + \frac{1}{3}(x-1)^4 + \mathrm{O}((x-1)^5) \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!} (x-1)^n
\end{align}
(where $a_n$ is [A005727](http://oeis.org/A005727)) and plugging in the derivative operator $x = \mathrm{D}$, noting that
\begin{align}
\left(\mathrm{D}-1\right)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (-1)^{n-k} \mathrm{D}^k
\end{align}

Comment: I am reading your answer after 2 months while reading my old questions. What is the formula for $a_n$?

Comment: See [Lehmer Comtet constants](https://oeis.org/A005727)